# When is the displacement current equal to conduction current in case of a parallel plate capacitor being charged?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

I came across a text - "Whenever a conduction current is oscillating in time, the displacement current is equal to the conduction current in case of parallel plate capacitor."

I am not sure what's oscillating in time means here!

Below is the question that triggered this :
(I am trying to discuss part (b) of the question)
[image]of the question)

Comment: The answer to (b) says it is equal to conduction current - 0.15 A .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that we have a uniform electric field between the plates of a capacitor, we can find its intensity to be (using Gauss' Law) $E(t)=\frac{\sigma(t)}{\epsilon_0}=\frac{q(t)}{\epsilon_0 A}$, where $q(t)$ is the absolute value of the charge on each plate, and which is not constant in time since the capacitor is being charged. Now, considering a circular surface between the plates, with same radius R and the same axis as the plates, the electric flux will be
$$\Phi_E(t)=E(t) S=\frac{q(t)}{\epsilon_0 A}\pi R^2=\frac{q(t)}{\epsilon_0}.$$
So, the displacement current is
$$I_D=\epsilon_0\frac{\partial\Phi_E}{\partial t}=\frac{dq(t)}{dt}=I(t),$$
hence, even if the current varies in time, the displacement current will be equal to it.

Comment: Would the result be same however the charge varies with time? Say, if the charge 'q' varies exponentially with time? I am trying to ask if it is a generalized that for every parallel plate capacitor displacement current between the plates must be equal to the conduction current?

Comment: I am convinced by what you wrote, thanks, but this apparently does not answer my question.

Comment: Yes it would. I'll edit the post showing how.